# NSNull into a Struct with a property of type NSDate

Tags: swift

I have an object from the server that is recognized by Swift 2.1 as either NSDate or NSNull.  I want to put it into a struct with a property of type NSDate.
Is that possible? If not, how should I handle this to be type safe later when I use it?

```
    struct Data {
        var completedAt: [NSDate]
        var name: [String]
        var gender: [Bool]
    }
```

but sometimes completedAt comes from the server as NSNull:

```
completedAt = "<null>";
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my interpretation of the text in the question you didn't mean to declare the variables as arrays.

This is how I handle my parson and I think it works pretty neatly. 
The date formatter should probable not be initiated in every iteration of the constructor. If you won't use the date regularly you might want to keep the detesting until you need to parse the date or you can have a static date formatter utility that you only instantiate once.

```
struct Data {
    var completedAt: NSDate?
    var name: String
    var gender: Bool

    init?(dictionary: [String:AnyObject]) {
        //Guessing that you want some of the values non optional...
        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String, 
              let gender = dictionary["gender"] as? String 
        else { 
            return nil 
        }

        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

        //safe handle of optional values
        if let completedAtString = dictionary["completedAt"] as? String, completedAt = dateFormater.dateFromString(completedAtString) {
            self.completedAt = completedAt
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back. For each item that the server might provide, there is no guarantee whatsoever that you receive what you expect, since you cannot control the server. So you need to decide how to react to which input.

In the case of expecting a date for example (if your data comes in JSON, that means you likely expect a string formatted in a certain way), the actual data that you receive might be an array, dictionary, string, number, bool, null, or nothing. You might then for example decide that you want to interpret nothing or null or an empty string as nil, that you want to interpret a string containing a well-formatted date as an NSDate, and anything else a fatal error in a debug version, and as either nothing or a fatal error in a release version. On the other hand, if an NSDate is absolutely required then you might interpret anything that doesn't give an NSDate as an error.

Then you write a function that delivers exactly what you want and use it. That way you can parse complex data, with your code warning you when something isn't as it should be, and with your code either surviving any possible input, or deliberately crashing on wrong input, as you want it.